# jQuery Slice resize function

Tags: javascript, css

I need a script that makes:

if screen bigger than 480px then do this

```
(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
```

if screen between 320px and 480px then do this

```
$(".projects").slice(1, 8).css("margin", "10px");
```

I saw some scripts but did not really understand how to make this. Can anyone help me with this please?

I need to do this JavaScript because the slice only works with js. I can't do this with css.

Comment: What are you slicing?

Comment: I have nine 300px box and that.

Comment: Isn't it better to use media queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
var width = screen.width;
if (width >= 320 && width <= 480) {
    $(".projects").slice(1, 8).css("margin", "10px");
} else if (width > 480) {
    $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
}
```

To use the window size, use this:

```
var width = $(window).width();
```

To do this dinamically on window resize:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    $(".projects").css("margin", 0);  // you may want to do this to "reset"
    if (width >= 320 && width <= 480) {
        $(".projects").slice(1, 8).css("margin", "10px");
    } else if (width > 480) {
        $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm i paste to my js the last slice 3,6 works but when resize window then stay that not use slice 1,8 any idea :(? copy paste the code hm?

Comment: You asked for "screen size". That is not changing on resize. I think you mean "window size" then. I updated the answer with that.

Comment: oh sorry yes i need windows size? amugy magyar vagY? lecci megcsinalod ugy ha valtoztatom az ablakot akkor valtson at?

Comment: koszonom nagyon hasznos :D am ez csak ugye akkor megy ha azon az oldal mereten toltodik be az oldal? ha esetleg valtozik akkor ujra kell tolteni?

Comment: Az utolsó kóddal nem kell. Azzal dinamikusan frissülni fog.

Comment: am valamit elrontotam mert nem toltodik be? xd bocsi de ugy masoltam be ahogy van copy paste :\

Comment: ha ott van ez is window.resize(function () { akkor nem indul el xd?

Comment: Nem, bocs, én írtam el. Javítottam. `window` helyett `$(window)` kell.

Comment: jah jo koszonom szepen xd :)))))

Comment: amugy tudunk valahol beszelni mashol? xd IRCen fentvagy?

Comment: ize most nem toltodik be az elso a 3,6 os csak az 1,8 as a kicsinyitsnel? xd bocsi mit rontotam el ;\

Comment: Na akkor még ennyit tudok segíteni: [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCetL/). IRC: nem igazán, sorry.

Comment: na ennel hasznosabbat koszonom szepen nagyon atlathato :)

Comment: Hálából kérhetek egy fölnyilat a válaszra? Köszi ;)
És további sok sikert.

Comment: igen persze csak uj vagyok es kell valami 15 rep nyavaja vagy mit ir de meglesz koszi meg1x